# Get unique every rows based on GROUP and LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with records and as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int(1) primary key, batch varchar(5), name varchar(5));
INSERT INTO test
  (id, batch, name)
VALUES
  (1, 1, 'Bob'),
  (2, 1, 'Jill'),
  (3, 3, 'Shawn'),
  (4, 2, 'Jake'),
  (5, 2, 'Paul'),
  (6, 2, 'Laura'),
  (7, 2, 'xxxx'),
  (8, 1, 'zzzz'),
  n ..........
```

I want to group based on batch (unique) ascending and limit = 4, so, basically query

```
SELECT * FROM test GROUP BY batch ASC LIMIT 4
```

but, this result desired

```
id batch name
1 1 Bob
4 2 Jake
3 3 Shawn
2 1 Jill
```

if I change limit to 5, the result is

```
id batch name
1 1 Bob
4 2 Jake
3 3 Shawn
2 1 Jill
5 2 Paul
```

and then only one batch found, let say is 2, the result

```
id batch name
4 2 Jake
5 2 Paul
6 2 Laura
7 2 xxxx
```

it possible? Iam using mysql 5.6 ver, give me advice. thankyou!

Comment: Please sync your sample data and expected output. Also explain what issue you are facing.

Comment: I have update in more case sir @mkRabbani

Comment: not understanding the last part. only one batch found, say 2? you mean to tell only one batch is present in the data ?

Comment: hi @VenkataramanR exactly, if we found only batch, for example is batch "two" is present the data based on batch "two" with limit N. I think the solution until now https://stackoverflow.com/a/59297887/5476036 but isn't work for me, because iam using mysql 5.6 versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql 5.6 you can use this not so efficient method to sort the results:

```
select t.* 
from test t
order by (select count(*) from test where batch = t.batch and id < t.id), t.batch
limit 4
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=0ca2c5ba6773bf157f0887f1f5452a3b).
Results (for each of your cases):

```
> id | batch | name 
> -: | :---- | :----
>  1 | 1     | Bob  
>  4 | 2     | Jake 
>  3 | 3     | Shawn
>  2 | 1     | Jill 

> id | batch | name 
> -: | :---- | :----
>  1 | 1     | Bob  
>  4 | 2     | Jake 
>  3 | 3     | Shawn
>  2 | 1     | Jill 
>  5 | 2     | Paul 

> id | batch | name 
> -: | :---- | :----
>  4 | 2     | Jake 
>  5 | 2     | Paul 
>  6 | 2     | Laura
>  7 | 2     | xxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use windowed functions to rank(), the first of each batch, then order by batch

```
select id, batch, name
from test
order by 
rank() over (partition by batch order by id) asc, 
rank() over (order by batch) asc
limit 5
```

see the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f113800a38dd097848d3032e734a385

for old mysql version need to work with variables to do the trick, like this

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SET @previous_batch:=0;

select id, name, batch
from (
SELECT 
@row_number:=IF(@previous_batch = batch, @row_number+1, 1) AS row_number_per_batch,
@previous_batch:=batch as set_batch,
id, batch, name
from  test order by batch
) V
order by row_number_per_batch, batch
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=171b5f551ce38e3967088570034cb561

Comment: I'm forget sir.. Iam using mysql 5.6, so sad :(

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
select t.* from test t
inner join 
(select batch, min(id) id from test 
group by batch) g
on g.batch = t.batch and g.id = t.id
order by t.batch asc limit 4
```

Comment: in their samples of expected result the same batch should appear more than one time if has a empty slot in the expected result number..

your query return only one for each batch

Answer (score 0):

The below query works in mysql 8.0. Refer to [db Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tHmtTjfk7k5ziaBSJahiFn/0). I have updated the query to return the data in batches.

```sql
SELECT id,batch,name, rnk
FROM
(select id,batch,name,rank() over(partition by batch order by id) as rnk 
FROM test) AS t
ORDER BY rnk
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: in their samples of expected result the same batch should appear more than one time if has a empty slot in the expected result number..

your query return only one for each batch

Comment: @Frederic, thanks. still I am confused about last resultset. I have put a comment to OP to clarify.

Comment: yes it was a confuse to me in the first moment too.
in my first answer I did misunderstood the question thinking that he wanted only the first of each batch but when validating my results with their samples, i got it.